# Django dynamic card redactor / processor showing on landing page

Tags: python, html, django

My goal is to have my website’s home page appear [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i96uQ.jpg) where only the form block element is present (marked by the large red “A”). After the website visitor enters their card number on that landing page, Django should redact it and render the same home page but the form should be gone and only the field divider with the processed output showing (marked by the large red “B”) [as it appears in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJHY4.jpg) on imgur. How do I achieve this? These two pics are kind of like a ‘mock up’, meaning  I just commented out the form and divider sections. When only A shows when B is commented out, I lose the functionality.

For the functionality to work, ‘A’ and ‘B’ shows at the same time [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrdSa.jpg), which is not what I want.

I need to modify the template (perhaps by adding conditional logic?).  I’m not sure how to tell Django to  serve the template so that only ‘A’ shows first and then, after the site visitor enters their 12 digit card number, remove ‘A’ and only show ‘B’.

Here is **[the template](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/6b75a00e4f272485930227a7bab93e9a230c9b8b/templates/alls/landings.html)** that I am working with showing the card processor form/divider elements:

```
   <div class="card-processor">
   <h1>A</h1>
   <h3>Enter your fake Chuckee Cheese Neptune membership card number!</h3>
  
   <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="get">
    
     <div> 
       <label for="password">Enter Card Number:</label>
       <input type="text" id="password" name="ccEntry" pattern="[0-9]{12}" maxlength="12"/>
       <div class="requirements">Must be a 12 digit number and no letters. </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Redact!" class="button"/>
     </div>
 
   </form>
  
   <h1>B</h1>
   <h3>Here is your fake Chuckee Cheese Neptune membership card number!</h3>
   <h3 style="color:lime">This was the original number that you entered:</h3>
   <div class="field">{{ number }}</div>
   <h3 style="color:lime">Here it is redacted:</h3>
   <div class="field">{{ redacted_num }}</div>    
   <a href="{% url 'posts' %}"><div class="field"><strong>Again? Click here!</strong></div></a>
  
 </div> <!--- END card-processor -->
```

For what it is worth, here is my card processor’s **[views.py](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/6b75a00e4f272485930227a7bab93e9a230c9b8b/redactors/views.py)**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from posts.models import Posts
 
def home(request):
   if 'ccEntry' in request.GET:
       number = request.GET['ccEntry']
       redacted_num = 'xxxx xxxx {}'.format(number[-4:])
       posts = Posts.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
       # context = {'posts':posts}
       return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', {'number':number, 'redacted_num':redacted_num, 'posts':posts, })
   else:
       return render(request, 'alls/landings.html')
 
def redactors(request):
   return render(request, 'alls/landings.html')
```

I gather that Javascript would probably be much better suited to implement this feature but right now I am focusing on Python and Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from what i understood, you want the A part displayed first, and then if the form is valid i.e. if the card number is valid, you want to hide the form, and display the membership card number i.e part B.

You can achieve this by using DTL as such:

```
<div class="card-processor">

   {% if not temp %}

   <h1>A</h1>
   <h3>Enter your fake Chuckee Cheese Neptune membership card number!</h3>
  
   <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="get">
    
     <div> 
       <label for="password">Enter Card Number:</label>
       <input type="text" id="password" name="ccEntry" pattern="[0-9]{12}" maxlength="12"/>
       <div class="requirements">Must be a 12 digit number and no letters. </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Redact!" class="button"/>
     </div>
 
   </form>

   {% else %}

   <h1>B</h1>
   <h3>Here is your fake Chuckee Cheese Neptune membership card number!</h3>
   <h3 style="color:lime">This was the original number that you entered:</h3>
   <div class="field">{{ number }}</div>
   <h3 style="color:lime">Here it is redacted:</h3>
   <div class="field">{{ redacted_num }}</div>    
   <a href="{% url 'posts' %}"><div class="field"><strong>Again? Click here!</strong></div></a>
  
   {% endif %}

 </div> <!--- END card-processor -->
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from posts.models import Posts
 
def home(request):
   if 'ccEntry' in request.GET:
       number = request.GET['ccEntry']
       redacted_num = 'xxxx xxxx {}'.format(number[-4:])
       posts = Posts.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
       # context = {'posts':posts}
       return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', {'number':number, 'redacted_num':redacted_num, 'posts':posts, "temp": True})
   else:
       return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', "temp": False)
```

The way this works is when you pass `temp` as `False` i.e. when the form is not valid, then the if block is evaluated to `True` and part A gets displayed. If `temp` is `True`, then the else block gets executed, rendering the B part.

Comment: If the answer helps you: https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~0159d078645b69be2d